# Atom, a game where you guess where hidden Atoms are located

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to code a simple game called 'Atom'. The game is like this: At the start, you press 'Play' and one of the three boards (5x5, 6x6 or 7x7) are generated. There you have to guess where the hidden Atoms are through clicking on the squares on the left, right, top and bottom.

After pressing one of the squares a "line" is either sent to the other side or it comes back. If it goes through, there were no atoms on the way. If it comes back, it means, that an Atom is on the way.

Back to my code: it works without any problems but I have a little problem. Visual Studio shows me that the complexity of a few codes in are pretty high: from 10 to 20 or even up to 26.

How can I reduce the complexity of these codes? Or are there any other ways to write some parts of the code different?

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    atom_game.start();

    document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", function() {
        atom_game.reset();
    });
    
    document.getElementById("solve").addEventListener("click", function() {
        let win = atom_game.checkForWin();
    
        const resultField = document.getElementById("result");
    
        if(win){
            resultField.innerText = "You win";
            resultField.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0, 255, 0)";
        }
        else{
            resultField.innerText = "You lose";
            resultField.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
        }
    });
});


const atom_game = {
        board: [],
        htmlBoard: [],
        fieldSize: 8,

    start(){
        this.randomBoardSize(5, 7);
        this.board = this.buildBoard();
        this.htmlBoard = this.buildBoard();
        this.buildHTMLBoard();
        this.setBorder();
        this.setAtoms();
        this.setBoardStyle();
    },

    reset(){
        const field = document.getElementsByClassName("field");
        const resultField = document.getElementById("result");
        const fieldLength = field.length
        for(let i = 0; i < fieldLength; i++){
            field[0].remove();
        }
        resultField.innerText = "";
        resultField.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
        this.start();
    },

    checkForWin(){
        let winner = true;
        for(let i = 0; i < this.fieldSize; i++){
            for(let j = 0; j < this.fieldSize; j++){
                if(this.htmlBoard[j][i].classList.contains("atom")){
                    if(this.htmlBoard[j][i].classList.contains("suspectAtom")){
                        this.setField(j, i, "correct");
                    }
                    else{
                        this.setField(j, i, "wrong");
                        winner = false
                    }    
                }
                else if(this.htmlBoard[j][i].classList.contains("suspectAtom")){
                    if(!this.htmlBoard[j][i].classList.contains("atom")){
                        this.setField(j, i, "wrong");
                        winner = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return winner;
    },

    randomBoardSize(min, max){
        this.fieldSize = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max+1 - min) + min) + 2;
    },

    setBoardStyle(){
        const field = document.getElementsByClassName("field");
        const sizeProzent = 100 / this.fieldSize;
        for (let i = 0; i < field.length; i++){
            field[i].style.width = sizeProzent + "%";
            field[i].style.height = sizeProzent + "%";
        }
    },

    buildBoard() {
        const board = [];
        for(let y = 0; y < this.fieldSize; y++){
            board.push([]);
            for(let x = 0; x < this.fieldSize; x++){
                board[y].push("null");
            }
        }
        return board;
    },

    setBorder(){
        for(let y = 0; y < this.fieldSize; y++){
            for(let x = 0; x < this.fieldSize; x++){
                if(x == y || (x === 0 && y === this.fieldSize-1) || (y === 0 && x === this.fieldSize-1)){
                    continue;
                }
                if(y == 0 || x == 0 || y == this.fieldSize-1 ||  x == this.fieldSize-1){
                    this.board[x][y] = "borderField";
                    this.htmlBoard[x][y].classList.add("borderField");
                }
            }
        }
    },

    setAtoms(){
        const min = 2;
        const max = this.fieldSize - 2;
        for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            let atomNearby = false;
            let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
            let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
            for(let yTest = y-1; yTest <= y+1; yTest++){
                for(let xTest = x-1; xTest <= x+1; xTest++){
                    if(this.htmlBoard[xTest][yTest].classList.contains("atom")){
                        atomNearby = true;
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
            if(atomNearby === false){
                this.setField(x, y, "atom");
            }
        }
    },

    buildHTMLBoard(){
        const divBoard = document.querySelector("#board");
        
        for(let y = 0; y < this.fieldSize; y++){
            for(let x = 0; x < this.fieldSize; x++){
                let field = document.createElement("div");

                field.classList.add("field");
                field.setAttribute("data-x", x);
                field.setAttribute("data-y", y);

                field.addEventListener("click", event => this.onClick(event));
                divBoard.appendChild(field);
                this.htmlBoard[x][y] = field;
            }
        }
    },

    onClick(event){
        let t = window.setTimeout(this.clearBorder, 2000);
        while(t--){
            window.clearTimeout(t);
        }

        const clickedField = event.target;
        const x = parseInt(clickedField.getAttribute("data-x"));
        const y = parseInt(clickedField.getAttribute("data-y"));

        if(clickedField.classList.contains("borderField")){
            this.clearBorder();

            if(x == 0) {
                this.setField(x, y, "rightArrow");
                this.calculateTrajectory(x, y, "right");
            }
            else if(y == 0){
                this.setField(x, y, "downArrow");
                this.calculateTrajectory(x, y, "down");
            }
            else if(x == this.fieldSize-1){
                this.setField(x, y, "leftArrow");
                this.calculateTrajectory(x, y, "left");
            }
            else if(y == this.fieldSize-1){
                this.setField(x, y, "upArrow");
                this.calculateTrajectory(x, y, "up");
            }
        }
        else if(clickedField.classList.contains("suspectAtom")){
            clickedField.classList.remove("suspectAtom");
        }
        else if(x > 1 && y > 1 && x < this.fieldSize-2 && y < this.fieldSize-2){
            this.setField(x, y, "suspectAtom");
        }
    },

    setField(x, y, val){
        this.board[x][y] = val;
        this.htmlBoard[x][y].classList.add(val);
    },

    clearBorder(){
        let border = document.getElementsByClassName("field borderField");
        const borderLength = border.length;
        for(let i = 0; i < borderLength; i++){
            border[i].className = "field borderField";
        }
    },
    calculateTrajectory(x, y, direction){
        const originalX = x;
        const originalY = y;
        const originalDirection = direction;
        do {
            let nearbyAtoms = [];

            nearbyAtoms = this.checkForAtoms(x, y);
            direction = this.calculateDirection(x, y, nearbyAtoms, direction)
            //console.log(nearbyAtoms, direction, x, y);

            switch(direction){
                case "right":
                    x++;
                    break;
                case "left":
                    x--;
                    break;
                case "up":
                    y--;
                    break;
                case "down":
                    y++;
                    break;
            }

        }while(!(x == 0 || y == 0 || x == this.fieldSize - 1 || y == this.fieldSize - 1))

        this.setCorrectExitImage(originalX, originalY, x, y, originalDirection, direction);
    },

    checkForAtoms(x, y){
        let nearbyAtoms = [];
        let minY = y - 1;
        let maxY = y + 1;
        let minX = x - 1;
        let maxX = x + 1;

        minY = minY < 0 ? 0 : minY;
        maxY = maxY > this.fieldSize-1 ? this.fieldSize-1 : maxY;
        minX = minX < 0 ? 0 : minX;
        maxX = maxX > this.fieldSize-1 ? this.fieldSize-1 : maxX;

        //console.log(y, minY, maxY, "  ", x, minX, maxX);
        for(let i = minY; i <= maxY; i++){
            for(let j = minX; j <= maxX; j++){
                if(this.htmlBoard[j][i].classList.contains("atom")){
                    nearbyAtoms.push([j, i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return nearbyAtoms;
    },

    calculateDirection(x, y, nearbyAtoms, direction){

        if(nearbyAtoms.length == 0){
            return direction;
        }

        const nearbyAtomX = nearbyAtoms[0][0];
        const nearbyAtomY = nearbyAtoms[0][1];

        if(nearbyAtoms.length == 2){
            return this.reverseDirection(direction)
        }
        else{
            //console.log(nearbyAtomX, nearbyAtomY);
            if(direction == "right" || direction == "left"){
                if(nearbyAtomY == y){
                    return this.reverseDirection(direction);
                }
                else if(nearbyAtomY > y){
                    return "up";
                }
                else if(nearbyAtomY < y){
                    return "down";
                }
            }
            else{
                if(nearbyAtomX == x){
                    return this.reverseDirection(direction);
                }
                else if(nearbyAtomX > x){
                    return "left";
                }
                else if(nearbyAtomX < x){
                    return "right";
                }
            }
            return direction
        }
    },

    reverseDirection(direction){
        switch(direction){
            case "right":
                return "left";
            case "left":
                return "right";
            case "up":
                return "down";
            case "down":
                return "up";
        }
    },

    setCorrectExitImage(originalX, originalY, x, y, originalDirection, direction){
        if(originalX == x && originalY == y){
            if(originalDirection == "left" || originalDirection == "right"){
                this.setField(x, y, "horizontalArrows");
            }
            else{
                this.setField(x, y, "verticalArrows");
            }
        }
        this.setField(x, y, direction + "Arrow");

    }
};
```

Comment: Do you mean cyclomatic complexity? Not time and memory complexity, right? Although of course I suppose you won't mind improving either :)

Comment: I wrote this code in VisualStudio and theres a feature, which tells you how complex each methods are. And I have many methods over 10. As an example my method calculateDirection(...) has a complexity of 26 xD. And my question is: how can I reduce the complexity of this code? Or how can I write the code different but still does the same thing?

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I placed your code in my Visual Studio Code setup and received similar messages. I use [SonarLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarlint-vscode) (super annoying, but effective) and it complained at the level of nested if/for/while/try blocks in addition to complaining about complexity of the functions. It might be too complex for a single function to `check for win` when so many steps need to be taken to determine this. Refactoring could include extracting code out of the function and applying `DRY principles` to your code.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you mean cyclomatic complexity? Not time and memory complexity, right? Although of course I suppose you won't mind improving either :)

it's cyclomatic, i.e. logic, complexity.  I bet a donut that `checkForWin` has the worst score. The number and depth of logic and control branches seem to have the primary impact on score.

---

It is best to focus on relative scores vice absolute numbers. Some understanding the scheme behind [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) can help but for goodness sake do not shred code in search of a arbitrary lower score. Instead, use it as a guide for possible refactoring. MSDN/Visual Studio documentation should have more to say about it too.

---

Good Object Oriented design manages complexity. Good objects hide state and expose functionality.

The atom game board should be an independent object encapsulating the square-iterating, with appropriate case-specific methods as needed. It may be quite complex but that complexity is isolated and confined, and gone from all other code.

A high complexity score for a given method/function is fine if that complexity is exposed by useful functions, where client code does not have to access the board's structure directly which would perpetuate that complexity and add some more in dealing with it. And on, and on, ....